# Android, TalkBack, support for blind users with short attention span

Tags: audio, accessibility, text-to-speech, talk-back, custom-sounds

I would like to know what Android does to support blind Android users with sort attention span.

One of the problems with these users, is, that while the user interface talks, the sound of the reading voice itself distracts them to the point where they focus on the sounds and not on the letters that make up the words. In this manner, they can never understand the words, that are being spoken out. The words are just spoken out too fast, and everything just goes too fast for them to keep track of everything.

What these users need, besides linear navigation in TalkBack, is a way to control the speed at which words and pauses are pronounced. They need to be able to drag out the pronunciation of the words over a long length of time. This slows everything down. Never mind. The point is that they must understand. Not only, they must be able to memorize and keep track of what goes by while it is being spoken.

Ideally these users should be able to control, not only swiping forward and backward between one word and another to navigate, but also, the length of time for each letter to be pronounced. They should have access to quadruple tap and drag a slider to control the speed, which they need to change as needed while everything is read. Because, at any given point in time, their ability to focus on longer pronunciations or shorter pronountiations as reading speed changes, and there is always, at any given point of time, matching their awareness and awakeness, a right, optimal, speed, with which to read the words out aloud.

The same goes for sound clues. These, just like the words, should also be sounded out longer or shorter, to allow the blind user with attention problems to have the time they need, in their slowness, to focus on them, and say to themselves, "yes, I've heard the sound i recognize as being such and such", and this must take place before the sounds finishes. The user must be able to talk to themselves during the sound, not after, when the sound had finished and the user has forgotten about it before they were able to say anything to themselves, about it.

So, my question is, does Android have anything to support this feature, which would be indispensably necessary to make the device accessible to blind users with sort attention span?

Thanks.